# How to extract numbers (year) from string?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have sample strings, and I have to extract the year from pandas Dataframe. I am unsure of how to do it? I tried using the pandas extract method using regular expression but I am unsuccessful.

Input:

```
Césio 137 - O Pesadelo de Goiânia (1990)

Nattbuss 807 (1997)

Νόμος 4000 (1962)
```

Output:

```
1990

1997

1962
```

I have tried using the following regex: `\d\d\d\d`

But in the expression, `Νόμος 4000 (1962)`, I am not getting my expected result. I want to only extract `1962`, not `4000`.

I am aiming to extract the `year` from the expressions given.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Asking for tutorial references or personal help is off-topic here.

Comment: Please give a [mre] of what was unsuccessful. You can also read https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3001761

Comment: My sincere apologies. I have updated my issue. I shall make sure that it won't be repeated.

Comment: From the duplicate `df['col'].str.extract('.*\((.*)\).*')` if the duplicate answer, is helpful, be sure to upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very simple regex.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""Césio 137 - O Pesadelo de Goiânia (1990)
Nattbuss 807 (1997)
Νόμος 4000 (1962)"""), names=["input"])

myre = re.compile(".*\(([0-9]+)\).*")
df.assign(output=df.input.str.extract(myre))
```

### output

|  | input | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Césio 137 - O Pesadelo de Goiânia (1990) | 1990 |
| 1 | Nattbuss 807 (1997) | 1997 |
| 2 | Νόμος 4000 (1962) | 1962 |

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
strings = ["Césio 137 - O Pesadelo de Goiânia (1990)", "Nattbuss 807 (1997)", "Νόμος 4000 (1962)"]

for string in strings:
    str = string.split(" ")
    last = len(str) - 1
    print(str[last].replace("(","").replace(")",""))
```

Result:

```
1990
1997
1962
```